# Redis docker image cluster install for Swarm?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-swarm

I know that there is an Official Redis Docker image [here](https://github.com/docker-library/redis).  My question is basically: is there a way to automatically deploy that to a Docker Swarm setup?  The closest question I found to mine is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979226/redis-cluster-with-docker-swarm-using-docker-compose).

While I don't think it yet possible, I would like it to be able to adapt to the Swarm Cluster upon which it is running.  Said differently, this is not MY cluster, thus, for some customers it will be single node, others will have 3, the largest will have only 5.  Only one redis instance should ever run on a single node.  But the 3 node swarm should have 3 and the 5 node should have 5, automatically configured as a cluster.   Can a single `yml` file be setup in some way to have a Redis cluster automatically deployed for this - i.e. independent of knowing beforehand the details of the Swarm?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your number of worker nodes, you should be able to deploy a Redis service to each node by using my [Docker Stack yaml](https://github.com/behoyh/redis-swarm-cluster/blob/master/redis-compose-stack.yml):